# http-proxy is being questionable

Tags: javascript, http, proxy, roblox

I need some smart people to help me out with this. It doesn't make much sense to me since it's basically sending a request to the same exactly url but is ending up with different end results.

Here is a snippet of the code, I tried to set it up so it would be easy to understand the issue:

```
var test = "/users/1"
httpsProxy.web(req, res, {target: `https://api.roblox.com${test}`});

// Output: {"Id":1,"Username":"ROBLOX","AvatarUri":null,"AvatarFinal":false,"IsOnline":false}

var settings = {
    target: `https://api.roblox.com${req.url}`
};
console.log(req.url);
// Output: /Users/2

httpsProxy.web(req, res, settings)

// Output: {"errors":[{"code":404,"message":"NotFound"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the case sensitivity issues. Your `req.url` has upper case `Users` world. Try to apply [String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) before sending request or adjust way you have formed `req.url` ( preferable).

```
var settings = {
    target: `https://api.roblox.com${req.url.toLowerCase()}`
};
```

Important: Applying toLowerCase may introduce issues for you, so consider fixing root cause of having that work (`Users`) not in lower case or you can be more safe by using [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with RegExp.